# Klein-Gordon-Equation provides a Scalar Theory that doesn't contain Spin

Tags: quantum-spin, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I'm reading actually Schwabl's "Advanced Quantum Mechanics" and encounter an understanding problem while considering the Klein-Gordan-equation. Here the excerpt:

Obviously, since the eigen energies of free solutions are $E= \pm \sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$, the energy is not bounded from below. But I don't understand the conclusion why that means that then K-G-equation provide a scalar theory that does not contain spin and then could only describe
particles with zero spin.

Comment: Is the excerpt a quote? Which page?

Comment: A wave equation based on the dispersion equation $p^2=m^2$ like the Klein-Gordon can be constructed with a scalar, due to simple transformation properties of a scalar under rotations the particles described by it have spin zero. If you want a equation with spin (e.g. 1)  take the same dispersion relation and use a vector field: The equation is called Proca equation and the particles described by it have spin 1.

Comment: Possible duplicates by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/427732/2451

Comment: Hi KarlPeter. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.